# Trying to create an array based on this situation, jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create a multidimensional array. something like following code, 44 and 45 is the key. When var pro is 44, I want to get 'onset, frequency' and then split them by .split(','). how should I write this array. Appreciate.

```js
var pro = 44;
var global = [
     44 : ["onset",'frequency'],
     45 : ["onset"]
   ]
```

Comment: first make `global` an object and then `console.log(...global[pro])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you have to convert your global array in object like below. And then you can get value for the keys.

```
{"44":["onset","frequency"],"45":["onset"]}
```

please refer below snippet for more understanding.

```js
var pro = 44;
var global = {"44":["onset","frequency"],"45":["onset"]};
console.log(global[44]);
console.log(global[44].join(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, if you want to use an array of objects, you can do:

```js
var pro = 44;
var global = [
  {44: ["onset", 'frequency']},
  {45: ["onset"]}
];

var result = global.find(function(element) {
  return element[this] !== undefined;
}.bind(pro))[pro];

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));

console.log('First element: ' , result[0]);
console.log('Second element: ' , result[1]);
```